# Javascript AJAX stops in Firefox and Firebug with multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, firebug

So I have this problem when I click on someting in a web App which sends an ajax request and then I immediately click on ANOTHER TAB in Firefox (a tab with a completely different webpage) and if I go back to the original my script stopped working and Firebug doesn't show the requests anymore.

Is this a Firebug related problem or do I need to worry about production mode as well?

Does anyone ever have similar?

I heard Firebug used to have problems with other extensions and websites

Comment: Have you tried the same on Chrome? As a general rule, avoid thinking that an error will disappear on production. Experience shows actually things get worse. Is the script too long/complex to show here?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. Well the script is a complete framework and since I get an error when I'm not on the page it seems impossible to find out what causes it. As far as I know its only in Firefox.